# Why does the proper class construction of Stone–Čech compactification fail?

Tags: general-topology, logic, set-theory, compactification

Wikipedia's [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) on the Stone–Čech compactification gives several constructions of it, one which is this:

> One attempt to construct the Stone–Čech compactification of $X$ is to take the closure of the image of $X$ in $$\prod\nolimits_{f:X\to K} K$$
> where the product is over all maps from $X$ to compact Hausdorff spaces $K$. By Tychonoff's theorem this product of compact spaces is compact, and the closure of ''X'' in this space is therefore also compact. This works intuitively but fails for the technical reason that the collection of all such maps is a proper class rather than a set. There are several ways to modify this idea to make it work; for example, one can restrict the compact Hausdorff spaces $C$ to have underlying set $P(P(X))$ (the power set of the power set of $X$), which is sufficiently large that it has cardinality at least equal to that of every compact Hausdorff set to which $X$ can be mapped with dense image.

My question is, why does this construction of the Stone–Čech compactification "fail"?  Is there something illegitimate about an infinite product being a proper class, or about endowing a topology to a proper class?  Or is it about applying the axiom of choice to proper classes?  Or what?

Does the existence of $\prod\nolimits_{f:X\to K} K$ follow from either $NBG$ or $MK$?

Comment: Well, a topological space is a *set* equipped with a topology...

Comment: @AlexKruckman But in mathematics all the time we talk about things like class functions, class groups, etc.  So I don’t see an issue with defining a “class topological space”.

Comment: You can define all sorts of things but then you have to prove things about them. Since this product is too big to be a set, *a priori* you can't apply theorems to them which are theorems about sets, such as Tychonoff's theorem. Even to state compactness of this thing requires that you consider arbitrary collections of open subclasses of it, whatever that means, and maybe those collections need to be bigger than sets too.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Ok, let's say you define "class topological space" in a framework that can handle this definition, and you develop enough theory of class topological spaces to prove that the Stone-Čech compactification exists as a class topological space. Then all you've done is proven a less precise version of the usual theorem, which says that the Stone-Čech compactification exists as a (set) topological space.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Actually if I’m not mistaken, even when defined in terms of this proper class construction, the Stone-Cech compactification will still be a set and not a proper class.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan That's exactly my point... your theorem is *less precise*, because you've left out the part of the proof that shows that the object you constructed is actually (isomorphic to) a set.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I don’t see why, if you succeeded in proving sufficiently many results about class topological spaces, why you wouldn’t be able to prove that the object constructed in terms of proper classes is a set as opposed to a proper class.  So as far as I’m concerned the final result would be equally precise, not less precise, but this is all speculation until we find out if it can actually be done.

Comment: So isn't this your question: Why do we banish classes from topology and restrict to sets?

Comment: @PaulFrost I mean, it’s quite clear to me that we CAN define a notion of a “class topological space”.  What’s not clear to me, however, is whether having done so, we can prove the results we need to prove in order to carry out the construction of the Stone-Cech compactification.

Comment: The problem indicated in the quotation form Wikipedia is not that you get a proper-class topological space. It's that the index set of the product, the set of all continuous functions from $X$ into compact spaces, is a proper class. That means the product "space" is too big to even be a class. If you are comfortable with a set theory that allows not only classes but super-classes (that can have classes as members), then this product will be OK. (But if you ever want the Stone-Cech compactification of a super-class space, you'll need hyper-super-duper-class products.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass If you post an answer showing that this construction of the Stone-Cech compactification works (like Tychonoff’s theorem carries over etc.) if you allow for superclasses, I’d be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to give you a slightly more general perspective, assuming that you know a bit of category theory.

Let $Top$ be the category of topological space and $\bf CHaus$ the full subcategory of $Top$ given by compact Hausdorff spaces. Let $j\colon\bf CHaus \to Top$ be the inclusion functor.

The problem of finding the stone Čech compactification is equivalent to find a left adjoint $\beta\colon\bf Top \to CHaus$. Indeed, you search for a *universal compactification* in the following sense:  for any $f\colon X \to i(C) $ where $X \in\mathbf{Top}, C \in\mathbf{CHaus}$, there is a unique extension $ \beta X \to C$.

Does a left adjoint to the inclusion exist? We will invoke here the

**General Adjoint Functor Theorem**. If $C$ is complete and locally small and $R: C\to D$ preserve small limits, then $R$ has a left adjoint if and only if it satisfies the solution set condition.

The solution set condition can be stated as follows: for every object $Y \in D$, there exist a small set $I$ of maps $ Y \to R(X_i) $ that is "initial"; this means that for any $Z \in C$ and a map $Y \to R(Z) $, there exist some $i$ and a map $X_i \to Z$ so that

$$ Y \to R(Z) = Y \to R(X_i) \to R(Z) $$

The only if part is simple. If there exist an adjoint $L$, then $\{LY\}$ will be the solution set: for any $Y \to R(Z) $, by adjunction you have $LY \to Z$ , and it is a classical result that
$$ Y \to R(Z) = Y \to RLY \to R(Z) $$

**Conclusions**. Note that $\bf CHaus$ is stable for products and quotients, which gives that $\bf CHaus$ is complete. It is also locally small, because $\operatorname{Hom}(X, Y) $ is a set for any spaces $X, Y$. The inclusion preserve limits, because both products and quotients in $\bf CHaus$ are computed as in $\bf Top$.

Since hypothesis of GAFT are verified, the existence of the left adjoint is *equivalent* to find a small solution set. Since for any $f\colon X \to C$ where $C \in\bf CHaus$ this factors through $\overline{\operatorname{Im} f} \in\bf CHaus$, you can take the small solution set of compacts Hausdorff in which $X$ is dense, which is bounded in cardinality.

What I want you to focus on is that size can be a real issue, and there exist examples in which GAFT can't be applied; not because there is some argument involving classes that would do the job, but because the left adjoint *does not exist at all*. See example 3.1 at the nlab page:

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor+theorem

Comment: Some sources might also refer to the theorem as the "Freyd adjoint functor theorem".

Comment: Yeah, I knew it that way too, but try to pronounce FAFT... 

Comment: Thanks to Asaf for the useful edits!